# Do you feel Stack Overflow needs a general discussion forum?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

I love Stack Overflow, but I have to admit I get frustrated when I see how quickly and often subjective, opinion, not-programming-related-(enough), etc. questions get closed. I understand the motivation behind this. We don't want those type of posts (including this one) to clutter up the Unanswered/Hot/New sections, making it harder for legitimate questions to get attention. However, I have often seen a significant interest in those types of questions, which makes sense to me.

For me, most of the people in the circles that I run in wouldn't know what I was talking about if I asked them what is the ["Worst thing you've seen on code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78354/worst-thing-youve-seen-on-code-closed). This is just one of the many reasons it would be nice to be able to discuss such things here.

Am I alone in my desire to have a place on Stack Overflow where we can have discussions?

Comment: myspace.com - a place for friends

Comment: I should have posted this question here, however meta.stackoverflow.com isn't quite what I was talking about.

Comment: Wow, 2 minutes to get closed on stackoverflow.com that was fast

Comment: @Tnay: MSO is the correct place for discussing meta topics like this.

Comment: @Rich B. what I was saying was that, I should have posted THIS question here, but the types of questions that i am asking about, do not fit on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well time eventually solved this issue for me: [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

And as Mike pointed out, the new chat system works for this too- although currently its not very active (Maybe if I check back in another year I can amend this).

Comment: And the new chat system, perhaps?

Comment: Note that programmers.stackexchange.com no longer accepts "discussion" questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey interesting how this issues has evolved over time

Answer (score 3):

No discussions on Stack Overflow please. If you wish to discuss Stack Overflow, this is the place to do it, but please keep it on topic anyway.

If all you want is a place to discuss your favorite chair, by all means create your own site. If you are hooked on this format:

> http://stackexchange.com

If you are really clever, I recommend you make your own site that fits really well into the Stack Overflow paradigm, but then create (or have someone create for you) a GreaseMonkey script that will allow users that opt in to see discussions on questions as a tab or something similar on the main site.

Answer (score 2):

No, that would go against the rules/goals/direction of these sites.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out some of the suggestions here:

> [What is your favorite programming discussion forum, channel, or chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171571/what-is-your-favorite-programming-discussion-forum-channel-or-chat)

But, not SO. Because SO isn't a forum. If you're interested in finding out how weird lengthy discussions get when forced into the SO mold, take a look around this site (MSO)... it's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

"Meta" SO is different from something like a "Nerd Lounge."  Is that what you're getting at?

[Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) has the nice divisions of "[Tech Off](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Techoff/)" and "[Coffeehouse](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/)."

Answer (score 0):

I think opportunity knocks for someone to make a community based forum tightly coupled with SO. It certainly makes sense that people who interact answering each others questions would want to interact in other discussions. It doesn't have to be on SO, but it is a community waiting to happen.

Comment: thats what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

## YES, ABSOLUTELY

There most definitely needs to be a free-style open-ended discussion forum for Stack Overflow so that the **chatterboxes will stop cluttering up the main site**

- An official discussion site would be less work for the moderators.
- An official discussion site can run all kinds of non-programming ads and sell <strike>crap</strike> officially-sanctioned gear and paraphenalia to make more money to run and improve the main site.
- Finally, an official discussion site would make it *so much easier* to ignore discussion questions.